# Newick Standard and Overlaying other data

Tags: javascript, python, visualization, bioinformatics, etetoolkit

I am currently working with a massive Newick Tree. I am looking for an efficient way to overlay some other data I have about the nodes. I have tried using dendroscope and ETE but have little luck as ETE cannot handle my tree as it is massive and dendroscope is too basic to implement coloring. So I am wondering if anybody knows of any efficient ways to visualize my data?

(I understand this is an inappropriate question for SO I just have ran out of leads on this problem)

Comment: have you considered figtree (http://tree.bio.ed.ac.uk/software/figtree/)? Coloring is quite easy and you can get nice publication-quality figures with it.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that it looks very promising!

Comment: @user1981275 how can I overlay data with this program?